# Evaluate which is the higher number

Tags: unix, scripting

I'm trying to process a software release based on the version number, which should be picked up from here.

```
<!-- language: lang-sh -->

  if [ `expr ${rel_choice}\<2.24` -eq 0 ]; then    
  rel_223
      elif [ `expr ${rel_choice}\=2.25` -eq 0 ]; then
       rel_225
          elif [ `expr ${rel_choice}\>2.25` -eq 0 ]; then
           rel_226
 else

 lp_error "Could not evaluate release number"

 fi
```

The problem i'm having is this, no matter what number i choose the program runs only the rel_223 function.
Here is the debug output.

```
 Enter stream required for BSB?: 2.25
 The Client is BSB
 The Release number is 2.25
 The build directory is ACEV225
 + expr 2.25<2.24
 + [ 2.25<2.24 -eq 0 ]
 + echo rel_223
 rel_223
 + read
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual value of `$rel_choice`? Have you tried those `expr` commands stand-alone in a shell?

Comment: Yeah the $rel_choice is this part in debug:The Release number is 2.25

Comment: Why do you expect 0 as result from your first `expr`? Right now I have no `expr` to test but the online help says: "Exit status is 0 if EXPRESSION is neither null nor 0, 1 if EXPRESSION is null or 0". Could it be that 2.25<2.2.4 resolves to something else than 0 and `expr`returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> [ `expr ${rel_choice} "<" 2.24` -eq 0 ]

Note that here the operator is quoted and separated by blanks from the operands. For me it worked:

```
expr 1 "<" 2
1

expr 1 "<" 1
0

expr 1 "<" 0
0
```

The version I tried is:

```
expr --version
expr (GNU coreutils) 8.24
Packaged by Cygwin (8.24-3)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: I'm runing this on SunOS not always as friendly as Linux..
I eventually went with a less than pretty way.

         if [ `${rel_choice}| sed 's/\.//g'` -le 224 ]; then
           echo rel_223
          elif [ `${rel_choice} | sed 's/\.//g'` -eq 225 ]; then
                 echo rel_225
            elif [ `${rel_choice} | sed 's/\.//g'` -gt 225 ]; then
            echo rel_226
             else
                lp_error "Could not evaluate release number"
               fi

Thanks